# Is it possible to use OmniSharp as code editor in my application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, editor, omnisharp

I have an application with some configuration where you can write some code in C# - this code is compiled to the memory and used as a plugin. I have an editor with IntelliSense, but this is a poor solution (IntelliSense is so simple). I saw a presentation where Atom was used as a code editor and OmniSharp was used as IntelliSense source.

Is it possible to use one of the OmniSharp supported editors for my application? If yes, how can I do this? - as plugin or as an embedded editor?

Explaining. I can use it as seperate editor (start as external process) but I wonder if it is possible to use it as embedded editor in my forms (like Office API).

Comment: We can't guess what is your problem with only that information. As i read, you want to use OmniSharp IntelliSense in a plain text editor like Atom. Well, any is valid for your application, you would prefer using an IDE, like Visual Studio, which is the one that i recommend. Please, extend your question and make it follow our general rules and standards. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for review and suggestions.

Comment: So you want to know if OmniSharp can be opened as a standalone program, or to include OmniSharp IntelliSense to your form?

Comment: Exactly what I would get.

Comment: Did you conclude anything on your quest for a custom editor @Klaudiuszbryjamus?

Comment: No. I still use Mono.Cecil and 3'rd party RichText as editor and don't use OmniSharp.